# Vue-cli-build fails with following error ValidationError: child "navigateFallbackWhitelist"

Tags: npm, webpack, vue-cli

I am currently working on a vue.js 2 project that uses vuetify pwa and vuex dependencies
When i try to build my project the cli throws the following error:

```
ValidationError: child "navigateFallbackWhitelist" fails because ["navigateFallbackWhitelist" at position 0 fails because [the value must be a RegExp]]
ValidationError: child "navigateFallbackWhitelist" fails because ["navigateFallbackWhitelist" at position 0 fails because [the value must be a RegExp]]
    at Object.exports.process (C:\Users\BluRRayS\Documents\ProostWebApp\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\errors.js:202:19)
```

I already tried to reinstall all my NPM packages and to update them to their latest version.
I Also tried to pull my project freshly from github but that didn't work either.
Since I do not have much experience with webpack or front-end software engineering in general I really am a bit stuck so any help would be much appreciated.
What causes this error and how could I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling around I found out that my vue.config.js wasn't valid after updating my npm packages.

```
module.exports = {
  "pwa": {
      // My Settings are in here
    },
    "workboxOptions": {

      "navigateFallbackWhitelist": [
       // Removed this empty object-> {}
      ]
    }
  },

  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
}
```

I Had to remove the empty object from `navigateFallbackWhitelist`